# Как динамически выводить время в шаблоне Angular2

Tags: angular2, datetime

Изучаю Angular2.
Есть вывод переменной в хедере шаблона компонента:

```
<div class="header-block header-block-search">
    {{ date | date:'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss' }}
</div>
```

В самом .ts компонента:

```
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
date: Date = new Date();
...
```

1. Как сделать вариант, чтобы время (секунды) динамически менялись на странице?
2. Как сделать вариант для формата времени date:'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm', чтобы символ ":" мигал каждую секунду?

Понимаю интуитивно, что нужно смотреть в сторону создания асинхронного пайпа,
но пока не нашёл пример, как именно его реализовать.

Comment: Можно по таймеру каждую секунду значение обновлять

Answer (score 0):

Удалось решить первый вопрос следующим образом:

**header.component.html**

```
<div class="header-block header-block-search">
   {{ date | async | date:'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss' }}
</div>
```

**header.component.ts**

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { Subscriber } from 'rxjs/Subscriber';

@Component({
selector: 'exd-header',
templateUrl: './header.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./header.component.css']
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

date = new Observable<string>((observer: Subscriber<string>) => {
setInterval(() => observer.next(new Date().toString()), 1000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Первую часть по моему можно было сделать так:

```
<div class="header-block header-block-search" 
     [attr.innerText] = "date | date:'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss'">
</div>
```

А контроллер можно было сделать через тот же `setInterval`